# Axios interceptor not working when initialized in a react Higher Order Function

Tags: reactjs, axios

**I have a Component which makes a axios get**

```
Component <using axios instance> {
   componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('myurl.jn').then(ingredients => { <wrong url>

    }).catch( error => {
      console.log(error) // dosent even show here as we donot propagate the error
    })
    }
}
export default hoc(Component,axiosInstance)
```

**Higher Order Funcfor Component**

```
const ErrorHandler = (WrapperComponent, axios) => {
    return class extends Component {

        componentDidMount(){
            axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                console.log(req) // none
                this.setState({error : null});
                return req;
              });

            axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res,(error) => {
                console.log(error) // none
                this.setState({error : true});
              });
        }
```

I tried adding logger and breakpoints to all the places in the hoc which uses the axios instance but to no effect nothing gets called .

**The only place the interceptor is picked up in the place where i create the instance why and how do we solve this. The console for browser throws 404 but not caught by interceptor.**

*I am very new to react and axios just learning for past week please pardon if not following any proper guidelines*

Comment: I would advise against using an interceptor each time the component mounts (possibly even the cause of the problem).

Comment: @EmileBergeron but this is the base component of my app and will always be in view no routing as of now .. so i donot thing as far as know its a problem but yes you are right but still this should work shouldn't it ..

Comment: If it's global error handling, get that out of React altogether and maybe wire that elsewhere, like in a Redux store? Though you should definitely rethrow the error so to let the other components (or anything using this axios instance) handle the error.

Comment: havent yet ventured into redux still with react and components still pretty new wanna take it step by step . I am following lectures by max schwarzmueller for react .. it works for him not for me  :(

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? So we can see exactly what's not working. Your example is minimal, but not "verifiable" as there is invalid syntax used, making it harder to spot typos and problems.

Comment: this is the branch file - https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/Learning-React/blob/react_project/src/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder.js and also the HOC is present . I hope this helps

Comment: I meant in the question itself, don't dump the whole project in here, but make your current example verifiable.

Comment: I am not able to do so with regard to that , Its already minimal but i am not sure how can i show it verifiable other than just showing the repo

Comment: By verifiable, I mean that you should use valid code in your example.